# Woocommerce: Show variable price instead of "From" price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been searching for this for quite a while now and i can't find any solutions.

I am looking for a way to **display the products variation prices inside the "From:" price field**, in order to have only 1 price shown on the product page.

I have tried this:

```
function woocommerce_template_single_price() {
global $product;
if ( ! $product->is_type('variable') ) { 
    woocommerce_get_template( 'single-product/price.php' );
}}
```

But it doesn't work for me, The price should change dynamicaly when a different product variation is selected. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately no, there is a way to get the prices for each product variable but it requires PHP skills which i don't have. I managed to it with CSS by moving the variation price on top of the from price for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'check_if_variable_first' );
function check_if_variable_first(){
    if ( is_product() ) {
        global $post;
        $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
        if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            // removing the price of variable products
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );

// Change location of
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_wc_template_single_price', 10 );
function custom_wc_template_single_price(){
    global $product;

// Variable product only
if($product->is_type('variable')):

    // Main Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
    $price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    // Sale Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
    sort( $prices );
    $saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    if ( $price !== $saleprice && $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        $price = '<del>' . $saleprice . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</del> <ins>' . $price . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</ins>';
    }

    ?>
    <style>
        div.woocommerce-variation-price,
        div.woocommerce-variation-availability,
        div.hidden-variable-price {
            height: 0px !important;
            overflow:hidden;
            position:relative;
            line-height: 0px !important;
            font-size: 0% !important;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('select').blur( function(){
            if( '' != $('input.variation_id').val() ){
                $('p.price').html($('div.woocommerce-variation-price > span.price').html()).append('<p class="availability">'+$('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html()+'</p>');
                console.log($('input.variation_id').val());
            } else {
                $('p.price').html($('div.hidden-variable-price').html());
                if($('p.availability'))
                    $('p.availability').remove();
                console.log('NULL');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php

    echo '<p class="price">'.$price.'</p>
    <div class="hidden-variable-price" >'.$price.'</div>';

endif;
}

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: The code shows user the price of the selected variation.